# Proxy authentication ubuntu 13.04

Tags: apt, updates, proxy

I newly installed the Ubuntu 13.04. then connected to the network, through wire, wireless, and  mobile broad band. I can browse in Firefox, I cant update software and I cant download new software.
software updater had this massage,

```
**Check your Internet connection.**
W:Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required
, W:Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required

, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

thanks

Answer (score 4):

You are behind a proxy server and you have not added your proxy authentication parameters in `/etc/apt/apt.conf`. Add your proxy authentication parameters in `/etc/apt/apt.conf`. To do this:

1. Open a terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
2. Type `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf` (or `sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf`) and type your password when it prompts you.
3. In the window that opens up, type the following, replacing `username` by your username, `password` by your password, `host` by your proxy host, `port_no` by your proxy's port number:

   ```
   Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:password@host:port_no";
   Acquire::https::proxy "https://username:password@host:port_no";
   Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://username:password@host:port_no";
   Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://username:password@host:port_no";
   ```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save and exit.

Comment: now i am typed /etc/apt/apt.conf, then i received this massage bash: /etc/apt/apt.conf: Permission denied, what are you doing now?

Comment: try `sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf`

Answer (score 1):

Check the file `sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf`.

After applying the proxy "system wide", the contents of /etc/apt/apt.conf are like:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://172.16.0.2:8080/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://172.16.0.2:8080/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://172.16.0.2:8080/";
```

Here `ipadress-of-proxy-server:port` I am using `172.16.0.2:8080` as sample. Use your proxy server address and port whatever you have. But, in order to make this work, you must add your `username` and `password` into it (unless you use an unnamed proxy) as follows:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://<username>:<password>@172.16.0.2:8080";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://<username>:<password>@172.16.0.2:8080/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://<username>:<password>@172.16.0.2:8080/";
```

To edit the file run in the following command in terminal (instead of `gedit` you can use your any text-editor if you wish):

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

Next save the file and run the following command in terminal to make system understand the changes in APT's settings:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Here you are good to go to install things from both a terminal and the Software Center.

(Note that by the `apt.conf` settings the proxy will only work on software-center/terminal with apt-get.)

There is more information here at [AptGet/Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto) in the Ubuntu [official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/).